# if record exists update else insert sql vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have the following problem, I am developing a Clinic application using vb.net, the doctor has the ability to add medical information using checkboxes checkbox2.text = "Allergy" textbox15.text is the notes for Allergy, I want to insert the record if the patient's FileNo(Textbox2.text) doesn't exist, if it does then update the notes only, so far I was able to update it after 3 button clicks I don't know why????

any help is appreciated :)
thanks in advance

```
    Dim connection3 As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim command3 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim adaptor3 As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dataset3 As New DataSet
    connection3.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + My.Settings.strTextbox + ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
    command3.CommandText = "SELECT ID,Type FROM Medical WHERE FileNo='" & TextBox2.Text & "';"
    connection3.Open()
    command3.Connection = connection3
    adaptor3.SelectCommand = command3
    adaptor3.Fill(dataset3, "0")
    Dim count9 As Integer = dataset3.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    If count9 > 0 Then
        For countz = 0 To count9
            Dim A2 As String = dataset3.Tables("0").Rows(countz).Item("Type").ToString
            Dim B2 As Integer = dataset3.Tables("0").Rows(countz).Item("ID")
            TextBox3.Text = A2
            If A2 = CheckBox1.Text Then
                Dim sql4 As String = "update Medical set MNotes=N'" & TextBox22.Text & "' where FileNo='" & TextBox2.Text & "' and Type = '" & CheckBox1.Text & "' and ID='" & B2 & "';"
                Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand(sql4, connection3)
                Try
                    cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
            ElseIf A2 = CheckBox2.Text Then
                Dim sql4 As String = "update Medical set MNotes=N'" & TextBox15.Text & "' where FileNo='" & TextBox2.Text & "' and Type = '" & CheckBox2.Text & "' and ID='" & B2 & "';"
                Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand(sql4, connection3)
                Try
                    cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
            End If
        Next
    Else
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            Dim sql4 As String = "insert into Medical values('" & CheckBox1.Text & "',N'" & TextBox22.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
            Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand(sql4, connection3)
            Try
                cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
        If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
            Dim sql4 As String = "insert into Medical values('" & CheckBox2.Text & "',N'" & TextBox15.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
            Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand(sql4, connection3)
            Try
                cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If

    End If
```

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: sql server database file

Comment: You should be using parameters to do anything like this. `command3.CommandText = "SELECT ID,Type FROM Medical WHERE FileNo='" & TextBox2.Text & "';"` is a sure fire method for receiving [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: hahahaha I am not worry about getting hacked because its a school project never going online

Comment: Is this the code behind the button click?

Comment: Still, MAX, it's a good practice to get into and may even earn you extra points for your project.

Comment: Yea, and I thank you for your advice will sure read more about sql injection and how to prevent it

Answer (score 1):

I think one of your problems may be related to your reducing the count of your table rows by 1 and then testing it above 0:

```vbs
Dim count9 As Integer = dataset3.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
If count9 > 0 Then
```

Try changing to:

```vbs
Dim count9 As Integer = dataset3.Tables(0).Rows.Count
If count9 > 0 Then
```

Also, make sure one of the check-boxes (`CheckBox1` or `CheckBox2`) mentioned later in your code is ticked.

**-- EDIT --**

Sorry - didn't explain why! The reason is that the majority of array/list like structures in .NET are zero based (i.e. start counting from 0 instead of 1).

Comment: Index out of range exception "there is no row at position 1"

Comment: Which line does the program stop on?

Comment: Also, what's in `TextBox2`?

Comment: On Dim A2 As String and textbox2 contains patient's file number

Comment: Ok. When you debug you can test values of variables by placing your pointer over the variable name. Test out the value of `countz` to see where it breaks...

Comment: Use the `F11` key to step through your code thereafter.

Comment: the value of countz is zero always, after I hit the button 3 times it updates in the database

Comment: Ok - with your breakpoint set, have a look at `Command3.CommandText`, then copy it out and run it in SQL Server Management Studio as a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

The best course of action for you is to maximize your productivity by allowing SQL to do what it does best.  Assuming you are using SQL Server 2008, the [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) function is an excellent use case for the conditions that you have supplied.

Here is a very basic example that is contrived based upon some of your code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[csp_Medical_Merge]
    @MType int, @FileNo varchar(20), @MNotes varchar(max), @ID int,  @OtherParams
AS
BEGIN

MERGE INTO [DatabaseName].dbo.Medical AS DEST
USING 
    ( 
        /*
            Only deal with data that has changed.  If nothing has changed,
            then move on.
        */
        SELECt @MType, @MNotes, @FileNo, @ID, @OtherParams
        EXCEPT
        Select [Type], MNotes, FileNo, ID, OtherFields from [DatabaseName].dbo.Medical
) As SRC ON SRC.ID = DEST.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        DEST.MNOTES = SRC.MNOTES,
        DEST.FileNo = SRC.FileNo,
        DEST.Type = SRC.Type
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (FieldsList) 
    VALUEs (FileNo, MNotes, etc, etc);

END
GO
```